# Change transparency of symbols in R function plotrix::polar.plot()

Tags: r, plot, transparency, visualization, plotrix

Is there a simple way to control the transparency of the blue circles in the function below to control the overplotting.

```
library(plotrix)
polar.plot(1:5000, rnorm(5000,90,30), rp.type='s', point.col='blue')
```

I'm hoping for some transparency parameter, usually called `alpha`, between 0 and 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but an easy one is using the `rgb` function. Here is an example with 50% transparency.

```
polar.plot(1:5000, rnorm(5000,90,30), rp.type='s', point.col=rgb(0,0,1, 0.5))
```

Comment: or `adjustcolor("blue",alpha=0.5)`

Comment: @Ben. Do you mean `point.col = adjustcolor("blue",alpha=0.5)` parameter or some other?